# UITableView messed up

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I am trying to put an UITableView inside an UIViewController, but when I try to run the app this is how it looks :
[image]

Any idea why/what the big white space is ?

Comment: When you run your app, there's a button called "Debug View Hierarchy" near the step in/out buttons.  Click that and see which views are visible and their locations.

Comment: @PhillipMills Thanks , it says its the UITable , but still not sure why the cell is on the "second" place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the UITableView is the first child view of your ViewController. Just like bellow:
[image]

Anchor the top of the TableView in the of the superView. Not bellow the Navigation Bar.

This is how your tableView constraints might be.

[image]